# Error while downloading ATI/AMD additional drivers

Tags: drivers, ati

I get the following error when I try to install the drivers for ATI/AMD:

[image]

What's up with this?

Answer (score 0):

i got same problem :S
but follow this guide, and i hope that is the solution for u.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.